# Push elements from one array into rows of another array (one element per row)

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, merge, append, array-push

I need to push elements from one array into respective rows of another array.

The 2 arrays are created from `$_POST` and `$_FILES` and I need them to be associated with each other based on their indexes.

```
$array1 = [
    [123, "Title #1", "Name #1"],
    [124, "Title #2", "Name #2"],
];

$array2 = [
    'name' => ['Image001.jpg', 'Image002.jpg']
];
```

New Array

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 123,
    1 => 'Title #1',
    2 => 'Name #1',
    3 => 'Image001.jpg',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 124,
    1 => 'Title #2',
    2 => 'Name #2',
    3 => 'Image002.jpg',
  ),
)
```

The current code I'm using works, but only for the last item in the array.
I'm presuming by looping the `array_merge` function it wipes my new array every loop.

```
$i = 0;
$NewArray = array();
foreach ($OriginalArray as $value) {
    $NewArray = array_merge($value, array($_FILES['Upload']['name'][$i]));
    $i++;
}
```

How do I correct this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$i=0;
$NewArray = array();
foreach($OriginalArray as $value) {
    $NewArray[] = array_merge($value,array($_FILES['Upload']['name'][$i]));
    $i++;
}
```

the [] will append it to the array instead of overwriting.

Comment: `$OriginalArray` already has indexed keys.  Just use those in the `foreach` instead of manually incrementing your own counter variable.

Answer (score 28):

Use either of the built-in array functions:

`array_merge_recursive` or `array_replace_recursive`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php

Comment: This vague hint of an answer is provably incorrect or needs to be explicitly demonstrated. Proof: https://3v4l.org/5Hgf8  Voters, please be careful not to ruin Stack Overflow by voting up answers that do not work.

Answer (score 3):

Using just loops and array notation:

```
$newArray = array();
$i=0;
foreach($arary1 as $value){
  $newArray[$i] = $value;
  $newArray[$i][] = $array2["name"][$i];
  $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify rows by reference while you iterate.  Because you have an equal number of rows and name values in your second array.  Use the indexes from the first array to target the appropriate element in the second.  Just push elements from the second array into the first.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/6JDPU))

```
foreach ($array1 as $i => &$row) {
    $row[] = $array2['name'][$i];
}
var_export($array1);
```