# Is it possible to merge these arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: Merge 2 Multidimensional Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558291/php-merge-2-multidimensional-arrays)

I have these arrays and I want to merge them into one array.

```
$arrayAAA[0]['name'] = "stackoverflow";
$arrayBBB[0]['color'] = "white";
$arrayCCC[0]['media'] = "web";
```

I want to merge these like this.

```
$newArray[0]['name'] //"stackoverflow"
$newArray[0]['color'] //"white"
$newArray[0]['media'] //"web"
```

If anyone knows how to do this, please give me a help.
I thought I could merge them by using `array_merge()`, but this function doesn't work in my case.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: honest mistake with php's mess of function names

Comment: sorry! I meant array_merge(). I tried this function but this didn't give me the result I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, this does not work either?

```
$x = array();
$x[0] = array_merge($arrayA[0], $arrayB[0], ...);
```

There is also [array_merge_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) function. But I am pretty sure it would only append each sub-array.

Comment: what if `$arrayAAA` contains more than one element?

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im well then that additional element will be ignored

Comment: actually, $arrayAAA has 40 element. $arrayAAA[0]['key'] ~ $arrayAAA[40]['key']

Comment: @crzyonez777 you should have mentioned that then ;)

Comment: @dualed sorry about that. but your advice worked perfectly for my case.

Answer (score 6):

I dont know how much time you have wasted finding the solution while you could have written a manual one.

```
foreach(array($arrayAAA, $arrayBBB, $arrayCCC) as $v){
    foreach($v as $iv){
        $result[key($iv)] = $iv[key($iv)];
    }
}
```

**[CodePad](http://codepad.org/BdSRebMZ)**

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to use `array_merge()`, not `merge_array()`

Comment: `array_merge()` won't give that result exactly.

Comment: It doesn't work with multi-dimensional arrays?

Comment: It does, but won't produce that result. It will add keys for each sub-array like `Array([0] => Array ([name] => stackoverflow) [1] => Array([color] => white) [2] => Array([media] => web))`  In the OP's example, all the keys are members of the `[0]` array.

Comment: Ohhhh, that's interesting then. My apologies for the incorrect answer

Comment: sorry! I meant array_merge(). I tried this function but this didn't give me the result I want.

Answer (score 2):

For more complex arrays this should work, but seems like there should be an easier way.

```
$arrayAAA[0]['name'] = "stackoverflow";
$arrayBBB[0]['color'] = "white";
$arrayCCC[0]['media'] = "web";

function merge_arrays(){
    $aArgs = func_get_args();

    $aReturn = array();
    if($aArgs != array()){
        foreach($aArgs as $aArr){
            foreach($aArr as $mKey => $aSub){
                if(!isset($aReturn[$mKey])){
                    $aReturn[$mKey] = array();
                }

                foreach($aSub as $mSubKey => $mVal){
                    $aReturn[$mKey][$mSubKey] = $mVal;
                }
            }
        }   
    }

    return $aReturn;
}

$newArray = merge_arrays($arrayAAA, $arrayBBB, $arrayCCC);
```