# How to combine one array in php

Tags: php

```
How to my array combine :
$visitor_tracvking_data = json_encode($array);
print_r($visitor_tracvking_data);
```

**Output print_r this:**

```
    array (size=6)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'tracktitle' => string 'search_engine' (length=13)
      'direct' => string '261' (length=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'tracktitle' => string 'search_engine' (length=13)
      'social_media' => string '3' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'tracktitle' => string 'search_engine' (length=13)
      'search' => string '3' (length=1)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'tracktitle' => string 'browser' (length=7)
      'chrome' => string '168' (length=3)
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
      'tracktitle' => string 'browser' (length=7)
      'firefox' => string '68' (length=2)
  5 => 
    array (size=2)
      'tracktitle' => string 'browser' (length=7)
      'netscape' => string '31' (length=2)
```

**How to out put this type:-**

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'tracktitle' => string 'search_engine' (length=13)
      'direct' => string '261' (length=3)
      'social_media' => string '3' (length=1)
      'search' => string '3' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'tracktitle' => string 'browser' (length=7)
      'chrome' => string '168' (length=3)
      'firefox' => string '68' (length=2)
      'netscape' => string '31' (length=2)
```

Comment: good. hier some one to do that. or put your code effort what you tried so for?

Comment: Loop through and use array_push

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558291/php-merge-2-multidimensional-arrays

Comment: Not merge array... Only one array and solve this...

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through the array and generate a new array with `tracktitle` key -

```
$new = array();

foreach($array as $key_top => $value) {
    foreach($value as $key => $val) {
        $new[$value['tracktitle']][$key] = $val;
    }
}

return $new;
```

OR for json encoded string -

```
return json_encode($new);
```

Comment: @GaurangP `$new` will hold the array.if you want to return the array the return `$new` or for json return json_encode($new). Simple.

Comment: My output:-  How to out put this type: in display.

But your output that in:- Output print_r this

Comment: @GaurangP check - https://eval.in/372338. The way you want. just two new keys instead of `0` & `1`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79104/discussion-between-gaurang-p-and-b0s3).