# PHP - Merge arrays and subtraction some value

Tags: php, arrays

Assume I have two arrays `$array1` :

```
array (size=3)
  0 =>
    array (size=5)
      'id' => int 16
      'project_id' => string '37' (length=2)
      'description' => string 'Guitar' (length=6)
      'qty' => int 87
      'uom' => string 'Units' (length=5)

  1 =>
    array (size=5)
      'id' => int 17
      'project_id' => string '37' (length=2)
      'description' => string 'Drums' (length=5)
      'qty' => int 889
      'uom' => string 'Drum' (length=4)

  2 =>
    array (size=5)
      'id' => int 13
      'project_id' => string '37' (length=2)
      'description' => string 'Bump' (length=4)
      'qty' => int 76
      'uom' => string 'Units' (length=5)
```

and `$array2` :

```
array (size=2)
  0 =>
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 17
      'qty' => int 800
  1 =>
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 16
      'qty' => int 87
```

I need some help:

- merge above arrays by `id` and do subtraction of `qty values`
- check if `qty values` less than or equal to `0` do not include in $result.

so the final `$result` would be:

```
array (size=2)
  0 =>
    array (size=5)
      'id' => int 17
      'project_id' => string '37' (length=2)
      'description' => string 'Drums' (length=5)
      'qty' => int 89
      'uom' => string 'Drum' (length=4)

  1 =>
    array (size=5)
      'id' => int 13
      'project_id' => string '37' (length=2)
      'description' => string 'Bump' (length=4)
      'qty' => int 76
      'uom' => string 'Units' (length=5)
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Hi, what have you tried?

Comment: Does array 1 have an equal number of values when compared to array 2? You have 3 in array 1 and 2 in array 2, is the data like this too?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Merge 2 Multidimensional Arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558291/php-merge-2-multidimensional-arrays)

Comment: @IndigoIdentity sorry if can't include what have I done, because what I tried nothing approach to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach($array1 as $a) {
    $match = false;
    foreach($array2 as $b) {
        if ($a['id'] == $b['id']) {
            $match = true;
            if (($a['qty'] - $b['qty']) > 0) {
                $a['qty'] -= $b['qty'];
                $result[] = $a;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(!$match) $result[] = $a; 
}
```

Comment: I tried over 4 hours to solving this problem, thank you for your help.