# merging of 2 identical keys in one array

Tags: php, arrays

Need help from the team,

I have this scenario of having 2 identical keys in each array with different values, i want them to be merged into one key were the values also are in it

example:

```
arrayData1(
 [2] => Array
        (
            [EXP1] => Array (records...)
            [EXP2] => Array (records...)
        )
)

arrayData2(
 [2] => Array
        (
            [EXP3] => Array (records...)
            [EXP4] => Array (records...)
        )
)
```

Having the output like this:

```
arrayFinal (
 [2] => Array
       (
           [EXP1] => Array (records...)
           [EXP2] => Array (records...)
           [EXP3] => Array (records...)
           [EXP3] => Array (records...)
       )
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: array_merge_recursive() might do it

Comment: possible duplicate of `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558291/php-merge-2-multidimensional-arrays`

Comment: ive tried but its no luck...arrayFinal = array_merge_recursive(arrayData1, arrayData2);

Comment: Use array_merge_recursive() as suggested above, that will append it to the array value of the key..and also you cannot have two same keys in a single array..that won't make sense

Answer (score 0):

First of all you cannot have two same keys in a single array, what you can do is use the array_merge_recursive function in php to merge both the arrays, and the repeating keys will have a new array with all the repeating key values..

```
$array1 = [
'EXP1' => [1,2,3],
'EXP2' => [2,3,4] 
];

$array2 = [
'EXP2' => [5,6,7],
'EXP3' => [8,9,10] 
];
```

Now there are two EXP2 keys, so when you use array_merge_recursive() you get something like this,

```
print_r(array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2));
```

> ```
> //output Array (
> [EXP1] => Array
>     (
>         [0] => 1
>         [1] => 2
>         [2] => 3
>     )
>
> [EXP2] => Array
>     (
>         [0] => 2
>         [1] => 3
>         [2] => 4
>         [3] => 5
>         [4] => 6
>         [5] => 7
>     )
>
> [EXP3] => Array
>     (
>         [0] => 8
>         [1] => 9
>         [2] => 10
>     )
> ```
>
> )

Comment: well currently that is the scenario..having the same key from a diff set of array datas..thanks anyway vince