# Merge the arrays

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays `$array` and `$array2`. I need to merge them on behalf of common key value i.e. entry_id. 
Well I need to merge them is such a way that if the entry_id of array 1 matches with the entry_id of array2, it merges. If the entry_id doesn't match that array remains as it but it should be entered in the merged array. I have tried but i didn't get the desired results. If it is possible to do this without function?

Thanks in Advance.

Here is my code

```
 <?php

$array = array(
    array(
        'title' => 'mytitleeee',
        'entry_id' => 1000
        ),
    array(  
        'title' => 'myt',
        'entry_id' => 1001
        ),
    array(  
        'title' => 'mytRRRR',
        'entry_id' => 1003
        ),
    array(  
        'title' => 'RUKES',
        'entry_id' => 1004
        )   
    );

$array2 = array(
    array(
        'author_id' => 'desc1',
        'entry_id' => 1000
    ),
    array(
        'author_id' => 'desc2',
        'entry_id' => 1001
    ),
    array(
        'author_id' => 'desc3',
        'DAY' => 'MON',
        'entry_id' => 1003
    ),
    array(
        'author_id' => 'desc7',
        'DAY' => 'TUE',
        'entry_id' => 1012
    )

);  
$x = array();
foreach($array as $value => $ans){

}   
foreach($array2 as $value1 => $ans1){

}   
if($ans1['entry_id']!= $ans['entry_id']){
    $x = ($ans1);
    echo"<pre>";
    print_r($x);

}
```

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558291/php-merge-2-multidimensional-arrays?rq=1

Comment: did you try using [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)?

Comment: Yes. I did it but i don't keeps the array in which entry_id does'nt match

Comment: @Core972, the Q&A you referred to is not really a duplicate. Here the two arrays may not have the same length, and their sub-arrays are only merged upon some condition.

Comment: yeah exactly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could apply this [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) call to the `array_merge` result:

```
$result = array_reduce(array_merge($array, $array2), function ($acc, $el) {
    $key = $el['entry_id'];
    $acc[$key] = isset($acc[$key]) ? $acc[$key] + $el : $el;
    return $acc;
}, []);
```

`$result` will have the following for your sample data:

```
array (
  1000 => array (
    'title' => 'mytitleeee',
    'entry_id' => 1000,
    'author_id' => 'desc1',
  ),
  1001 => array (
    'title' => 'myt',
    'entry_id' => 1001,
    'author_id' => 'desc2',
  ),
  1003 => array (
    'title' => 'mytRRRR',
    'entry_id' => 1003,
    'author_id' => 'desc3',
    'DAY' => 'MON',
  ),
  1004 => array (
    'title' => 'RUKES',
    'entry_id' => 1004,
  ),
  1012 => array (
    'author_id' => 'desc7',
    'DAY' => 'TUE',
    'entry_id' => 1012,
  ),
)
```

#### How it works

First the two arrays are merged:

```
array_merge($array, $array2)
```

This just appends the elements of the second array after those of the first.

This array is then passed to `array_reduce`, which calls the callback function -- given as argument -- for each element.

Furthermore, that function also gets an accumulated value (`$acc`), which in the first call is `[]` (provided as final argument to `reduce`). Whatever the function returns becomes the accumulated value that is passed in the second function call (for the second element), ...etc. The final returned value becomes the return value of `reduce`.

So in this case the accumulated value is an associative array that is keyed by `entry_id`. If at a certain moment that key already exists, the current value is merged with the value that is already in `$acc`: this merge is done with the `+` operator. If the `entry_id` of the current element is not yet in `$acc` it is added to it.

This `if...else` is implemented with the ternary operator (`... ? ... : ...`).

The `return`$acc`statement ensures that the the next time this callback is called (for the next element),`$acc` is again that accumulated value.

Comment: I added some explanation.