# PHP - Two array values to one

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to combine two multidimensional arrays to one array as the example provided below.

Booth arrays have same keys each time (0,1,2, ...)

**The first array**

The **url1** or **url2** are the same each time

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 1
            [Title] => Example
            [Url1] => https://example1.com
            [Url2] => https://example2.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 2
            [Title] => Example
            [Url1] => https://example1.com
            [Url2] => https://example2.com
        )

)
```

**Second array**

The keys of each array change every time (*AL_url*, *MK_url*, *EN_url*, *SR_url*, ...)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [AL_url] => ?api=123?label=al
            [MK_url] => ?api=456?label=mk
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [EN_url] => ?api=789?label=en
        )

)
```

**Final result**

The final array should lookalike:

[Url1] + [AL_url] + [MK_url] = https://example1.com**?api=123?label=al**?api=456?label=mk

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [complete_url_1] => https://example1.com?api=123?label=al?api=456?label=mk
            [complete_url_2] => https://example2.com?api=123?label=al?api=456?label=mk
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [complete_url_1] => https://example1.com?api=789?label=en
            [complete_url_2] => https://example2.com?api=789?label=en
        )

)
```

**The code**

```
for ($y = 0; $y < count($second); $y++) {

foreach ($second[$y] as $key => $value) {
$new[$y]['complete_url_1'] = $first[$y]['Url1'] . $second[$y][$key];

    }
}
```

The response add the value only from the last key from second array

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [complete_url_1] => https://example2.com?api=456?label=mk
**this should be  https://example1.com?api=123?label=al?api=456?label=mk**
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [complete_url_1] => https://example1.com?api=789?label=en
            )

    )
```

Comment: Have you tried `array_merge`?

Comment: I tried with foreach alone ,foreach in for lop but without success

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Merge 2 Multidimensional Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558291/php-merge-2-multidimensional-arrays)

Comment: Provide your code please.

Comment: _Why_? Your URLs are contradicting themselves... `https://example1.com?api=123?label=al?api=456?label=mk` has `api` and `label` set **twice**.. That can't be a good thing...

Answer (score 1):

I would just do a loop and create the strings to push in to the merged array:

Sorry about the function, I just reversed your printed out arrays, so i could use the data exactly how you have it.

Little information: **Your URLs are contradicting themselves**, this isn't the greatest idea!

The URLs should look something more like this:

https://example1.com?api=123?label=al

https://example1.com?api=456?label=mk

I've done my answer based on what you've requested in your question, if you'd like it based on how the links should look then please let me know.

**Test link:**
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/70537b81816d95c3ddda12c1b68ba5cb072505c5

```
<?php

$array1 = "Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 1
            [Title] => Example
            [Url1] => https://example1.com
            [Url2] => https://example2.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 2
            [Title] => Example
            [Url1] => https://example1.com
            [Url2] => https://example2.com
        )

)";

$array2 = "Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [AL_url] => ?api=123?label=al
            [MK_url] => ?api=456?label=mk
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [EN_url] => ?api=789?label=en
        )

)";

function print_r_reverse($in) {
    $lines = explode("\n", trim($in));
    if (trim($lines[0]) != 'Array') {
        // bottomed out to something that isn't an array
        return $in;
    } else {
        // this is an array, lets parse it
        if (preg_match("/(\s{5,})\(/", $lines[1], $match)) {
            // this is a tested array/recursive call to this function
            // take a set of spaces off the beginning
            $spaces = $match[1];
            $spaces_length = strlen($spaces);
            $lines_total = count($lines);
            for ($i = 0; $i < $lines_total; $i++) {
                if (substr($lines[$i], 0, $spaces_length) == $spaces) {
                    $lines[$i] = substr($lines[$i], $spaces_length);
                }
            }
        }
        array_shift($lines); // Array
        array_shift($lines); // (
        array_pop($lines); // )
        $in = implode("\n", $lines);
        // make sure we only match stuff with 4 preceding spaces (stuff for this array and not a nested one)
        preg_match_all("/^\s{4}\[(.+?)\] \=\> /m", $in, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE | PREG_SET_ORDER);
        $pos = array();
        $previous_key = '';
        $in_length = strlen($in);
        // store the following in $pos:
        // array with key = key of the parsed array's item
        // value = array(start position in $in, $end position in $in)
        foreach ($matches as $match) {
            $key = $match[1][0];
            $start = $match[0][1] + strlen($match[0][0]);
            $pos[$key] = array($start, $in_length);
            if ($previous_key != '') $pos[$previous_key][1] = $match[0][1] - 1;
            $previous_key = $key;
        }
        $ret = array();
        foreach ($pos as $key => $where) {
            // recursively see if the parsed out value is an array too
            $ret[$key] = print_r_reverse(substr($in, $where[0], $where[1] - $where[0]));
        }
        return $ret;
    }
} 

$array1 = print_r_reverse($array1);
$array2 = print_r_reverse($array2);

$newArray = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++) {
    if(isset($array2[$i]["AL_url"]) && isset($array2[$i]["MK_url"])){ 
        $newArray[$i][] = $array1[$i]["Url1"] . $array2[$i]["AL_url"] . $array2[$i]["MK_url"];
        $newArray[$i][] = $array1[$i]["Url2"] . $array2[$i]["AL_url"] . $array2[$i]["MK_url"];
    }

    if(isset($array2[$i]["EN_url"])){ 
        $newArray[$i][] = $array1[$i]["Url1"] . $array2[$i]["EN_url"];
        $newArray[$i][] = $array1[$i]["Url2"] . $array2[$i]["EN_url"];
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArray);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Upvote for producing two separate URLs that *do not* contradict themselves.

Comment: Thank you for the code , it does what i wanted but it throws an error if the "EN_url"  doesn't exist or any key from the second array.

Comment: @user3255412 Please check my test link, it won't throw an error if the "EN_url" doesn't exist as I've got a check with the if statement.

Comment: Yes in this case it doesn't throw an error but as i mentioned on the question the keys on the second array change as i request the array.

Comment: @user3255412 Could you show me a snippet of the code which generates your arrays? As I can adapt my code to work for your instance

Answer (score 0):

I finally achieved what i needed here is the code:

```
for ($y = 0; $y < count($second); $y++) {
    $final[$y]['complete_url_1'] = $first[$y]['complete_url_1']. implode('',$second[$y]);
    $final[$y]['complete_url_2'] = $first[$y]['complete_url_1']. implode('',$second[$y]);

}
```