# Array Merge from multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I want to merge the multidimensional array into single array . 
I want to know is there any `php built in array_function` to do this. I don't want to use any loop cause I have the data from import file . There could be more than thousands record.

I am generate this array below this code:

```
$insert = array();
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
   $insert[$key][] = [
        'name' => $value->name,
        'email' => $value->email,
        'mobile_no' => $value->mobile_no,
        'password' => bcrypt($value->password),
        'user_type_id' => $value->user_type_id,
        'designation' => $value->designation,

        $this->userTypeWiseFieldGenerateForImportInsert($value)
    ];
}
```

And my callback functions are

```
public function userTypeWiseFieldGenerateForImportInsert($data){
    if($data->user_type_id == 1){
        $insertArray['market_code'] = $data->market_code;
        $insertArray['product_code'] = $data->product_code;
        $insertArray['territori_code'] = $data->territori_code;
        $insertArray['region_code'] = $data->region_code;
        $insertArray['division_code'] = $data->division_code;
    }elseif($data->user_type_id == 2){
        $insertArray['territori_code'] = $data->territori_code;
        $insertArray['region_code'] = $data->region_code;
        $insertArray['division_code'] = $data->division_code;
    }elseif($data->user_type_id == 3){
        $insertArray['region_code'] = $data->region_code;
        $insertArray['division_code'] = $data->division_code;
    }elseif($data->user_type_id == 4){
        $insertArray['division_code'] = $data->division_code;
    }

    return $insertArray;
}
```

I get this array:

```
Array(
  [0] => Array
      (
          [name] => Md. XXXX
          [email] => abc@gmail.com
          [mobile_no] => 1751017812
          [password] => $2y$10$6Vmr61t896IxfJ1A0pxX5Of1hnfUVX9blmdmclAxt56cMd754NkDC
          [user_type_id] => 1
          [designation] => Sr. Software Engineer
          [0] => Array
              (
                  [market_code] => mirpurA203
                  [product_code] => Seclo201
                  [territori_code] => T352
                  [region_code] => Mirpur334
                  [division_code] => Dhaka31
              )
      )

  [1] => Array
      (
          [name] => Md. XX
          [email] => def@gmail.com
          [mobile_no] => 1761017812
          [password] => $2y$10$62fwqiAmrv.Jc89i5L3YNuMpcYeFVrpqewuBPKYIgmXiX/9sGRC/S
          [user_type_id] => 2
          [designation] => Sr. Software Engineer
          [0] => Array
              (
                  [territori_code] => T352
                  [region_code] => Mirpur334
                  [division_code] => Dhaka31
              )
      )
)
```

My expectation to make single array like:

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Md. XXXX
        [email] => abc@gmail.com
        [mobile_no] => 1751017812
        [password] => $2y$10$6Vmr61t896IxfJ1A0pxX5Of1hnfUVX9blmdmclAxt56cMd754NkDC
        [user_type_id] => 1
        [designation] => Sr. Software Engineer
        [market_code] => mirpurA203
        [product_code] => Seclo201
        [territori_code] => T352
        [region_code] => Mirpur334
        [division_code] => Dhaka31
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Md. XX
        [email] => def@gmail.com
        [mobile_no] => 1761017812
        [password] => $2y$10$62fwqiAmrv.Jc89i5L3YNuMpcYeFVrpqewuBPKYIgmXiX/9sGRC/S
        [user_type_id] => 2
        [designation] => Sr. Software Engineer
        [territori_code] => T352
        [region_code] => Mirpur334
        [division_code] => Dhaka31
    )
)
```

Comment: Have you tried something?or search on SO? Maybe this can help you [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558291/php-merge-2-multidimensional-arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558291/php-merge-2-multidimensional-arrays)

Comment: What you had tried ?

Comment: @Sfili_81 Thanks for comment i want some buit in array function without for loop

Comment: @MayankVadiya I am not trying anything i want some array buit in function cause i have 1000 row so i can't loop through this

Comment: Is the nested array `[0] => Array` always and only zero? Or could there be more? Why not use a foreach?

Comment: Always should be 0 @Thefourthbird

Comment: Something like https://3v4l.org/hUMGW

Comment: @Thefourthbird I am getting this field from import a file there can be more than 1000 row so i am not want to use any loop i want some array built in funciton to do this

Comment: Can you show how you load this data, it may be better to fix this than try and process the result.

Comment: @NigelRen I have just edited my question and put the code on this how to got the multidimentional array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your original import...

Your sub-function (`userTypeWiseFieldGenerateForImportInsert()`) is adding the sub-array into the data in the first place, you could instead create one part from the initial data, and merge in the additional data from this function call...

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $newData = [
        'name' => $value->name,
        'email' => $value->email,
        'mobile_no' => $value->mobile_no,
        'password' => bcrypt($value->password),
        'user_type_id' => $value->user_type_id,
        'designation' => $value->designation,
    ];
    $additionalData = $this->userTypeWiseFieldGenerateForImportInsert($value);

    $insert[$key][] = array_merge($newData, $additionalData);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would do the trick:

```
function flatten($arr){ 
    $res = []; 
    foreach($arr as $k=>$v){ 
        if(is_array($v)){ 
            $res= array_merge($res, $v); 
        }else{
            $res[$k]=$v;
        }
    }
    return $res;
};

$arr = ['one','two', 'three', ['four','five']];   
print_r(test($arr));
// Output: Array ( [0] => one [1] => two [2] => three [3] => four [4] => five )
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Updated, missed setting the indexes

Comment: Thanks for your answer . I know this tricks but i want to know is there any php built in array_function to do this. i don't want to use any loop cause i have the data from import file . There could be more than thousands record

Comment: @MD.JubairMizan There will be a for loop running somewhere. Built in functions just abstract it but that's what they do under the hood. Nothing wrong with writing your own for loop for it.

Comment: @MD.JubairMizan built-in functions perform the same iterations internally, there isn't any magic that they perform. PHP applications are capable of iterating over hundreds of thousands of records quickly, depending on the overall data size.

Comment: As @MD.JubairMizan stated, For what you need, this would get the job done. There will be some sort of loop going on somewhere. Also, as far as I am aware, there is not a built-in php function for this.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [array_walk_recursive()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) function. For example:

```
$array = /*your array example*/;
$filter = [];
foreach ($array as $index => $item) {
  array_walk_recursive($item, function($val, $key) use (&$filter) {
      if (strpos($key, 'territori_code') === 0) {
        $filter[$key] = $val;
      }
  });
}
```

Note: What's the criteria for deciding which keys to keep? 
I have a reference at: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/45281/merge-some-child-values-back-into-the-parent-multidimensional-array

Comment: Thanks for your answer . I know this tricks but i want to know is there any php built in array_function to do this. i don't want to use any loop cause i have the data from import file . There could be more than thousands record

Answer (score 1):

There is no PHP builtin function that can help you to achieve your goal easily, you have to go through loop or recursive function.

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved by using creating a simple function using `array_map().`

In the below code, merge_my_array() function will merge the multidimensional array into single, regardless of how may the nested array contains it.

```
$arr = array(
    0 => array(
            'name' => 'Md. 1111',
            'email' => 'abc@gmail.com',
            'mobile_no' => '111111',
            'password' => '$2y$10$6Vmr61t896IxfJ1A0pxX5Of1hnfUVX9blmdmclAxt56cMd754NkDC',
            'user_type_id' => 1,
            'designation' => 'Sr. Software Engineer',
            0 => array(
                    'market_code' => 'mirpurA203',
                    'product_code' => 'Seclo201',
                    'territori_code' => 'T352',
                    'region_code' => 'Mirpur334',
                    'division_code' => 'Dhaka31',
              )
        ),
    1 => array(
      'name' => 'Md. 222',
      'email' => 'def@gmail.com',
      'mobile_no' => '222222',
      'password' => '$2y$10$62fwqiAmrv.Jc89i5L3YNuMpcYeFVrpqewuBPKYIgmXiX/9sGRC/S',
      'user_type_id' => 2,
      'designation' => 'Sr. Software Engineer',
      0 => array
          (
              'territori_code' =>'T352',
              'region_code' => 'Mirpur334',
              'division_code' => 'Dhaka31',
          )

    )
);

$out = array();
array_map("merge_my_array",$arr);

echo "<pre> out: "; print_r( $out );echo "</pre>";




function merge_my_array( $elem ){
    global $out;
    if( is_array($elem) ){
        array_map( "merge_my_array", $elem );
    }else{
        array_push($out,$elem);
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve merge array also without for loop.

Can you try following codes?

```
function reduce(&$item, $key){
    $item = array_merge($item, $item[0]);
    unset($item[0]);
}       

array_walk($data, 'reduce');
var_dump($array);
```